# adding a top margin to flex centering

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following code which centers vert and horiz a div inside the jumbotron.

css

```
#s-text { 
text-align: center;
width: 65%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.jumbotron { 
position: relative;
min-height: 600px; 
width: 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
margin: 0; padding: 0;
border-radius: 0 !important;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="jumbotron" style="...">
        <div id="s-text">
            <h2> <?php the_secondary_title(); ?> </h2>              
            <p> ... more content ... </p>
        </div><!-- end of s-text-->
    </div>    
</div>
```

I have a 100px header fixed to the top of the page so there needs to be a 100px top margin/padding/space at the top so they don't overlap but the centering with flex doesn't seem to allow that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I think the additional flexbox for `#s-text` is not necessary. Even with more than one child inside `.jumbotron` it should be possible only with one flexbox. `text-align: center` on all children of `#s-text` should suffice. (inherit on children possible)

To the main problem:
before we get too deep into crazy things a rather obvious approach, which we all know is simple to oversee in too many cases while working for 12 hours straight :D

Does the layout allow padding / margin on `.row`?

Comment: I didn't know I could remove the extra flex, which I edited my question to show thank you. I have tried adding padding/margin to the jumbotron, s-text and the < p > inside with no change

Comment: But why can't you put padding / margin on the `.row`?

Comment: I tried that as well, however, by removing the extra flex I can add the margin to the s-text div directly. So you did answer my question thank you.